# What is the inf and sup for the sets?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, supremum-and-infimum

Consider
$$
X=\left\{\left.n+\frac{1}{n}\ \right\vert \ n\in\mathbb N^\ast\right\}
$$
is the $\inf X= 2$? and $\sup X=+\infty$? Also, for
$$M=\left\{\left.\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\ \right\vert \ n\in\mathbb N\right\} \cup \left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}$$

is the $\inf M=0$? and $\sup M =1$?

If yes,how to prove the values.

Comment: sorry, i thought latex is ok ,thx for your remark

Comment: @Jack: please upload questions with your thought progress on them.

Comment: @AnnaPham i did mention in the question the values I found but I asked here to be sure about them and to learn how to prove those answers

Answer (score 0):

For the first,

we have for $n>0$

$$n+\frac 1n=(\sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^2+2\ge 2$$

and
$$2 = 1+\frac 11 \in X$$
thus
$$\inf X =2$$

Given $A>0$, if we put

$$n = \lfloor A \rfloor +1$$
then
$$ n +\frac 1n > n \ge A$$
thus
$X$ is not bounded and $$\sup X =+\infty$$

For the second,

$$ 1=\frac{0+1}{0^2+1} \in X$$
and
$$(\forall n\in \Bbb N) \;\; \frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\le 1 \implies \sup X=1$$

the sequence $(\frac{n+1}{n^2+1})$ is decreasing and converges to $0$, thus
$$\inf X =0.$$

Comment: ok i understood ,how about the second one? (thx for the first)